# Wordpress wp.media Featured Image ID

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wp-editor

How can I hook into an existing wp.media object and grab the attachment ID when the "Set Featured Image" button is clicked?

The wp.media tutorials I've been looking at all seem to start by creating a new wp.media frame, but I just want to listen for events coming from an existing one (rendered by wp_editor() function), particularly the "Set Featured Image" event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the [`wp.media.featuredImage`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/js/media-editor.js#L627) object, and more specifically its `frame()` and `get()` methods:

```
// on featured image selection...
wp.media.featuredImage.frame().on( 'select', function(){

    // ...get the attachment ID
    var attachment_id = wp.media.featuredImage.get();

    console.log( attachment_id );

});
```